# multiple image upload to aws in laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, file-upload

**This is laravel project and I want to upload multiple images to aws s3 server**

This is blade code.

```
<div class="col-12">
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
<span>Add Multiple image...</span>
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" class="imageupload1" name="uploadfile2[]" /><br/>
</span>
</div>
```

And these are the Controller code.

```
        if($request->hasfile($file_name))
        {
            $file = $request->file($file_name);
            $originalFileName = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath = $defaultPath.'/'.$originalFileName;

            $this->deleteimage($profile->thumb_img);
            $this->uploadimage($request, $file_name, $filePath);
        }

    public function uploadimage($request, $file_name, $defaultPath){

        $this->validate($request, [$file_name => 'required|image']);

        if($request->hasfile($file_name))
        {
            $file = $request->file($file_name);
            
            \Storage::disk('s3')->put($defaultPath, file_get_contents($file));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below.
And let me know.

```
if($request->hasfile($multi_file_name))
    $files = $request->file($multi_file_name);

    foreach($files as $imgfile) {
        $originalFileName = time().$imgfile->getClientOriginalName();
        $multi_filePath = $multi_defaultPath.'/'.$originalFileName;
        \Storage::disk('s3')->put($multi_filePath, file_get_contents($imgfile));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the same.

Comment: Sorry. please change $multi_defaultPath to $multi_filePath in storage function call section.

Answer (score 0):

Since the request is coming through as an array, you need to loop through each iterance.

```
foreach ( $request->file($file_name) as $file )
{
     $originalFileName = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
     $filePath = $defaultPath.'/'.$originalFileName;

     $this->deleteimage($profile->thumb_img);
     $this->uploadimage($request, $file_name, $filePath);       
}
```